Сложное или простое это предложение?
Является ли предложение "Парнишка упал, однако не был убит." сложным или простым? Какое правило это определяет?

Парнишка упал, однако не был убит.
Пояснение
Это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми.
Чтобы определить вид предложения, надо обозначить его грамматическую основу.
Парнишка — подлежащее. Однако — союз,  связывающий однородные сказуемые. Грамматическая форма сказуемых разная, но это не имеет значения.
Второе сказуемое — составное именное, связка не был, именная часть выражена кратким причастием убит.
